# Google Play Purchases are not supported in your country - Demo Test Card

Tags: android

We get the following msg

[image]

This happens only in Russia using a demo test card, I guess this has something to do with the War,

but this a test card, not a real purchase,

This happens also with VPN

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: One of my app users from Portugal has reported this same error today when he tries to purchase my app subscriptions. This is thus unrelated to the war, and since you have opened this issue recently it could be actually a bug from Google.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable VPN, reset Google Play cache and try again